# How do you get contact_id in a custom form?

Tags: custom-fields

```
$contactId = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cid', 'Positive');
$contactId = (int) $_GET['cid'];
$contactId = $form->getVar('_contactID');
```

Are all possible solutions at different places, but none seem to work when in a Form_CustomData.

In this case the cust data is in an Activity for a civiCase

For the avoidance of doubt, this is to get the ID for the contact (not the user)

*Edit: additional info.*

Comment: Use any debugging technique to examine the $form variable at the point in the code where you want to use it, and see what's available. e.g. CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message(print_r($form, true)); to write to ConfigAndLog.

Comment: Um, well yes.   What I'm getting at is there does not appear to be anything which actually includes the cid.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a little more what you are after in what circumstances?

Generally speaking: when in a form Custom Data I would expect to see something like entityId or _entityID. Depending on the defintion of the custom group this would be the contact_id (or membership or activity etc.)

Comment: edited to give more info, but In this case the cust data is in an Activity for a civiCase

Comment: As Erik notes there is `$form->_entityId`, and then assuming you mean the "reported by"/"author" contact of the existing activity being edited, you can do `$result = civicrm_api3('Activity', 'get', ['return' => ["source_contact_id"], 'id' => $form->_entityId,]);` and then the contact id is in `$result['values']['source_contact_id']`.

Comment: OK, so the contact ID is not present in the form as I suspected.   Frustrating that the other forms of getting the contactID aren't maintained, but maybe there is a reason.

For other readers, just to clarify:  ErikH's comment only gets you the current entityID - so in other words an activityID if the current entity is an activity etc.   It doesn't get you the contactID unless you are in a contact.